# Testing the exhaust of a natural gas furnace?

Tags: hvac, furnace

I recently had maintenance performed on my natural gas forced-air furnace.  During this maintenance, the technician went outside and used an electronic handheld device with a wire-attached probe to check the exhaust gas vent while the furnace was running.  He explained that the purpose of the test is to determine if the heat exchanger may be busted.

What sort of device is used to perform such a test, what is it testing for, and how would the results of the test relate to a problem with the furnace?